# slideshow height changing on refresh with jquery slideshow

Tags: jquery, height, refresh, reload, jquery-cycle

here's an interesting one for you all!

My pages are loading a slideshow made using jquery cycle plugin absolutely fine. The slideshows have a variable height so I had to use some code to assess the height of each slide and resize the slideshow wrapper accordingly (as chrome was having a problem)

so it all works fine when you load the page - when you do that the inherited height of the slideshow is lost - so any text in the page below the slideshow moves up the page and behind the slideshow - only seems to be an issue with the first slide though, as it corrects itself after that...

here's an example page (please don't judge the rest of my code - this is just a development site, I know if needs cleaning up!!) - the text underneath (with the soundcloud embed) the image is the bit that's affected by the slide height.
http://www.frootful.co.uk/index-z.php/?p=7

and here's the code making the slideshow work (there's some play/pause functions in there too)

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#toggle').bind("click", function() {
    if ($(this).attr("class") == "play")
    $(this).attr("class", "pause");
    else
    $(this).attr("class", "play");
}); 
var toggle = $('#toggle').click(function() {
    var paused = slideshow.is(':paused');
    slideshow.cycle(paused ? 'resume' : 'pause', true);
}); 
var slideshow = $('#slideshow').cycle({
        fx:      "fade",
        pager:   "#single-slideshow-nav",
        timeout:  4000,
        prev:    "#prev",
        next:    "#next",
           after: onAfter,
        pause: true
    });
}); 
function onAfter() {
    //get the height of the current slide
    var $ht = $('.slidewrap').height();
    //set the container's height to that of the current slide
    $("#slideshow").height($ht);
} 
</script>
```

My javascript isn't great, so if people could explain answers that would be doubly helpful!

Thanks

EDIT -----------

added a better example page (http://www.frootful.co.uk/index-z.php/?p=7), as mentioned above the bit of text underneath is the bit thats beign affected by the slide height...

Comment: good point - changed to a better example page

Comment: Refreshed the page but it's still working.

Comment: I've just realised how poorly worded this question is - I'm going to rwwrite!! Basically-the slideshow continues to work, but it loses its height, making content disappear up the page behind it.

Comment: In my firefox, everything looks OK. After refresh, nothing including text disappears.

Comment: @sheen try a force refresh, (ctrl r) or looking at the site in safari - thanks

Comment: hmm...I just tried to look at your web site in safari of my mac. It's ( http://www.frootful.co.uk/index-z.php/?p=7) blank. but http://www.frootful.co.uk can be visible. Well, let me more investigate.

Comment: I can't find anything wrong yet. Sorry man. You'd better upload images or something in your question so we can understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

(At the time of answering.)  Your example page doesn't contain any slides, nor any div called `toggle`.

Your JavaScript contains two `$(document).ready` blocks both of which try to setup click handlers for `#toggle` (even though that doesn't exist.)  You could/should probably merge these into one code block.

I'm guessing the `paused` and `resumed` functions are meant to return a value, so you need to add a `return` to them both.  (i.e. `return !byHover;` if that's what you meant)

What else?  I guess you could try using add/remove/toggleClass instead of manipulating classes through `attr`, but I doubt that'll make a difference.

Comment: My mistake - it is actually a slideshow - but if there's only one slide, all navigation etc are hidden!! I'm adding a better example page to OP....

Comment: I've cleaned up some of the code there - doens't fix the issue unfortunately!